# Wrong images paths in github project pages with hugo / blogdown

Tags: r, blogdown

I'm using blogdown to build my blog with github pages. Since it's a project page of the form `https://<user>.github.io/<projec>/` I set `baseURL = "https://eliocamp.github.io/codigo-r/"` (trailing / and all) in my config.toml. Everything works fine except that images do not show up because the image paths are not rendered correctly in the underlying posts .html.

For example, instead of `<img src="https://eliocamp.github.io/codigo-r/post/2018-01-24-como-hacer-efecto-de-relieve-en-r_files/figure-html/unnamed-chunk-4-1.png" /><` the source code shows it's trying to get images from `<img src="https://eliocamp.github.io/codigo-r/codigo-r/post/2018-01-24-como-hacer-efecto-de-relieve-en-r_files/figure-html/unnamed-chunk-4-1.png" />` (so, it repeats the `<project>`

I'm building the site with `blogdown::build_site()`.

(Here's the whole site: https://github.com/eliocamp/codigo-r)

EDIT: As a workaround, it that setting `relativeURLs = true` [makes it work](https://blogs.colum.edu/marginalia/files/2017/06/makeitwork3.jpeg), but they are ugly as hell and doesn't seem to be standard. Is this the correct answer?

Comment: why do not you use something like imgur to host your images and then copy their links to your img tag ?

Comment: What is your version of blogdown?

Comment: I was using 0.5. Now I've installed the latest version from github (0.5.1) and the problem is still there.